# ¿por que no puedo descargar ninguna versiòn de sql server en windows 10?

Tags: sql-server

Resulta que cuando instalo slq server y me aparece una ventana para conectar, en esta hay una opción para elegir el servidor al que quiero conectar. El problema que tengo es que no me sale ningun servidor que por defecto deberia venir en e producto instalado. Recurro a ustedes por que desde ayer en la mañana estoy intentando y nada y ya necesito empezar a trabajar con C#.

Comment: Te sale la ventana `Connect to a Server`?. Deberías poder elegir en el `Authentication` la opción que se llama `Windows Authentication`. En la primera opción que es `Server Type`, elige la primera, se llama `Database Engine`. Debería ser los valores por defecto, pero, dale otro ojo y cualquier cosa nos dejas saber. Otra cosa, a parte de SQL Server, has instalado el Management Studio?, es importante para poder manipular tus bases de datos. Debes tener los dos instalados, `SQL Server` y `Management Studio`. El primero es tu `servidor`, el segundo es para manipular tus bases de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Debe validar que el servicio "SQl Server Browser" este ejecutándose, para realizar esto ingrese a "services.msc".

Tiene que tener abierto el puerto 1434.

[image: Sql Server Browser]

Comment: En realidad, por defecto es el puerto 1433. Otro punto es que no importa que el servicio mencionado esté activo, con que se escriba `localhost` en el nombre del servidor sería suficiente ;)